# Where in Azure is my .csv error files from the application are stored in Azure?

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver

In my application, I have a scenario where I send invites to multiple contacts by uploading a.csv files, also if the file is having erroneous or duplicate records those records will be assorted on another .csv [file with filename_errorlist.csv].

We publish this code on Azure. When we run those tests they are run on the server.

I am not sure where on the server those error files are stored.

P.S. I put those upload files in the utility folder.

Comment: So what is your question? Where do you require help?

Comment: I want to know, where on Azure those error files are stored.